# how to iterate through a particular attribute using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor inline on a webpage that i have built.I can save the data to a database but the major problem is that ckeditor applies its own classes and  other attributes to all the elements on which contenteditable is set to true.Also it removes some classes on elements. This is affecting the styling of my webpage. I wish to remove the classes and other attributes set by ckeditor before printing it on the browser.For this I need to loop through all the elements having content editable set to true. How can we do this using js?

Comment: something like `$("[contenteditable]")`

Comment: You should read how to correctly [retrieve data from CKEditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata) first.

Comment: i did read how to retrieve data from ck editor and and that how exactly i am retrieving data but the problem is this is data as changed by ckeditor(along with the new classes).I wish to have data without those new classes@oleq

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little.Like explain the code @dandavis

Answer (score 0):

<del>Plain JS:</del>
<del>var el = document.getElementsByTagName("*");</del>
<del>for(var i = 0, l = el.length; i < l; i++)</del>
<del>{</del>
    <del>if (el[i].contentEditable)</del>
    <del>{</del>
        <del>// Do here what you want

    <del>}</del>

}</del>

jQuery:

as **dandavis** said:

```
$("*[contentEditable]").each(function()
{
    // 
});
```

**Edit:**

As far as the .contentEditable does not return boolean,
you must check whether the element has the contentEditable attribute like this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for(var i = 0, l = el.length; i < l; i++)
{
    if (el[i].contentEditable === "true" || el[i].contentEditable === "")
    {
        // Do here what you want
    }
}
```

In order to remove the contentEditable attribute:
In jQuery you can do it like this:

```
$("*[contentEditable]").each(function()
{
    this.prop("contentEditable", false);
});
```

Plain js:

```
el[i].contentEditable = "false";
```

Comment: Plain JS method that is suggested here is just doing it for all the elements in the document rather than just the one's with contenteditable attribute.. I tried to add a counter inside the if statement and out side the if statement(both in the for loop). Both of those counters resulted in the same value. also i manually counted the contenteditable attribute in my document and the numbers vary drastically

Comment: and i still dont understand how to remove an attribute from a tag if that tag  has contenteditable attribute.. I am a little new to this. please help

Comment: @krishna jQuery does the same "behind the scenes", without checking all the elements in the document, you won't know which one has the contentEditable attribute.

          P.S. see EDIT

Comment: i tried this and recieved an error sayin this.prop is not a function